# An simple iterated integral

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I came across this double integral and I have no idea how to evaluate this deceptively simple double integral.

The double integral is:

$$\int_0^1\int_0^{3v}\sqrt{u+v}\ du\ dv$$

The integral $\int\sqrt{u+v}\ du$ looks like an common integral $\int\sqrt{u^2+v^2}\ du$ if we let $u = \sqrt u^2$ and $v=\sqrt v^2$, but when evaluating the mentioned integral, the result was so ugly that I'm lost.

How do you evaluate this above-mentioned iterated integral?

Comment: Why not first compute the inner integral as a usual integral, and then the outer integral?

Comment: Hi, do you know how to evaluate something like $\int \sqrt{u + 1} \ du$? (Perhaps by substituting $w = u + 1$? Or just by inspection?)

Comment: IOW, while doing the $u$ integration, you can treat $v$ as a constant.

Comment: I can't. There is a variable $v$ in the integral and the dummy variable is $du$. I don't know how to integrate $\int_0^{3v}\sqrt{u+v}\ du$. Partial integration is new to me.

Comment: I do know how to integrate $\int \sqrt{u + 1} \ du$. But when it comes to partial integration, it gets roughXD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With $u=vt$, the double integral is separable:

$$\int_{v=0}^1\int_{u=0}^{3v}\sqrt{u+v}\ du\ dv=\int_{v=0}^1\int_{t=0}^{3}\sqrt{vt+v}\ v\,dt\ dv=\int_{v=0}^1 v^{3/2}dv\int_{t=0}^3 \sqrt{t+1}\ dt=\frac25\cdot\frac{14}3.$$

Comment: Oh my. Never thought of that before. Strange, and thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For every suitable $v$ we have
$$
\int \sqrt{ u + v}du = \int \sqrt{u+v}d(u+v) = \frac{2}{3}(u+v)^{3/2} + \text{constant}
$$
by chain rule. Then by fundamental calculus theorem we have the inner definite integral as a "function" of $v$. Then integrate this function over $[0,1]$, which is elementary then.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing about this that requires anything more than the usual rule $\int (x+k)^a\, dx = \frac{1}{a+1} (x+k)^{a+1} + C$ for all $a \neq 1$. In this case, $$\int_0^{3v} \sqrt{u + v}\, du = \left. \frac{2}{3} (u+v)^{3/2}\right|_{u=0}^{u=3v} = \frac{2}{3} \left( (4v)^{3/2} - v^{3/2} \right) = \frac{14}{3} v^{3/2}$$
and then $$\int_0^1 \frac{14}{3} v^{3/2}\, dv = \left. \frac{28}{15} v^{5/2} \right|_{v=0}^{v=1} = \frac{28}{15}.$$

Comment: Gee! thanks,  Connor Harris! I hope other people will find my question. That was a fast response:-)